# Visual Studio Community 2015 crashes once when opening a project if SSMS 2016 is open

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015

A weird Visual Studio Community 2015 behaviour keeps happening regularly on my laptop. I can reproduce the issue with the following actions:

- Boot the laptop and login to Windows 10 (with the latest updates)
- Open SQL Server 2016 Management Studio (any version from 2016 RC3 to 16.4)
- Open Visual Studio Community 2015 (with Update 3)
- Open any recent project
  [Visual Studio crashes]
- Reopen Visual Studio Community 2015
- Reopen any recent project
  [Visual Studio loads the project without issues]

After a laptop reboot, the issue persists: the first load crashes, the second and the following ones don't crash.

If I open VS2015 and load the project without opening SSMS, the project loads even at the first try.

When VS2015 crashes, I get these two events:

.NET Runtime

> Application: devenv.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.SqmInteropServices.SqmApi.Increment(Microsoft.SqlServer.SqmInteropServices.HSQMSESSION, UInt32, UInt32)
>      at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Shell.Project.FileProjectHierarchy.Load(System.String, UInt32, Int32)
>      at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Shell.Service.DataWarehouseProjectManagerService.CreateProject(System.String, Int32, Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Designer.Serialization.DocumentObject, Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Shell.Project.IFileProjectManager, System.Guid)
>      at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Shell.Service.DataWarehouseProjectManagerService.CreateProject(System.String, System.Guid)
>      at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Shell.PVsProjectFactory.CreateProject(System.String, System.String, System.String, UInt32, System.Guid ByRef, IntPtr ByRef, Int32 ByRef)

and

Application Error

> Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 14.0.25420.1, time stamp: 0x57685d85
>   Faulting module name: msvcrt.dll, version: 7.0.14393.0, time stamp: 0x57899155
>   Exception code: 0xc0000005
>   Fault offset: 0x00088e5f
>   Faulting process id: 0x1fdc
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d213ec4b92254c
>   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
>   Report Id: a826a026-dc7d-42b3-b67c-e95cd57a7515
>   Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

I couldn't find any related topic, so I ask if anyone is facing the same issue.

Comment: try installing all windows updates and update to latest version of ssms/VS2015

Comment: Thanks, but everything's up to date (even with the 16.4 version of SSMS released yesterday)

Comment: And by the way, also SSDT is installed and updated at the latest version (14.0.60918.0)

Comment: try this `The reason it complains is because the file Microsoft.SqlServer.Sqm.dll should be located in two folders.
the first one is: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared" and the second one is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE"`

Comment: from this thread(https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/71e480ca-827c-4c44-898d-f9e5de1725e1/struggling-to-get-ssms-running?forum=sqltools)

Comment: Thanks @TheGameiswar, I'm trying to tweak the folders (no SQL Server 2008R2 here) mentioned in your reply and in the suggested thread, I hope to solve this annoying issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:

1. Visual Studio 2015 crashes the first time I try to open a solution.
   When I reopen VS everything works fine
2. I have significant delays opening new query windows in SSMS, and delays of 5-10 seconds trying to cut-and-paste code into a query window

I recently realized I only had problem #2 when VS2015 was open.

I finally decided to deal with it. Fix was to update SSDT from 14.0.61021.0 to 14.0.61707.300. Strange thing is, VS2015 told me I needed to update under Tools > Extensions and Updates, but downloaded a the old version for me. I had to go directly to the SSDT download page to get the most recent version.

Problem solved.